# How do I upload files via using Google Drive API on meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm using the Meteor framework to implement Google Drive API. I have generated clientId, clientSecret and redirectUrl.

In this method I have to get the url and when I clicked the Allow button, its redirect url which I have given in the redirect url. It's give the code in the url, I have save that code.

```
 checkForAuthorization = function() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   console.log("checkForAuthorization method is running......");
   var clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl, oauth2Client;
   clientId = "XYZ";
   clientSecret = "ABC";
   redirectUrl = "http://localhost:3000/home";
   oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, 
      redirectUrl);
   getGoogleDriveAccessToken(oauth2Client).then(function(result) {
     resolve(result);
   }).catch(function(error) {
    reject();    
   });
   });
  };
```

This code is for uploading the file. The login gives me an error saying that a login is required.

```
var uploadFileOnGoogleDrive = function(token) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         var fileMetadata = {
             'name': 'Claremont-Coral-Pillow-12x241.jpeg'
         };
         var media = {
               mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
               body: fs.createReadStream
                ('/home/administrator/Pictures/Claremont- 
                  Coral-Pillow-12x241.jpeg')
          };
         drive.files.create({
                    auth: token,
                    resource: fileMetadata,
                    media: media,
                    fields: 'id'
             }, function (err, file) {
             if (err) {
                  console.log("The error is ", err);      
             } else {
                  console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
             }
           });
         });
      };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the code that is made only for the terminal (command prompt).
As the documentation says itself on the below link

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs.

> The authorization flow in this example is designed for a command line
>   application. For information on how to perform authorization in other
>   contexts, see the Authorizing and Authenticating. section of the
>   library's README.

For your answer, you should go through and use the code given in the below API Doc link:-

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#authorizing-and-authenticating

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Let me check it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed the [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#AboutAuthorization) general process which is applicable to all applications.

> 1. When you create your application, you register it using the Google
>      API Console. Google then provides information you'll need later,
>      such as a client ID and a client secret.
> 2. Activate the Drive API in the Google API Console. (If the API isn't
>      listed in the API Console, then skip this step.)
> 3. When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for
>      a particular scope of access.
> 4. Google displays a consent screen to the user, asking them to
>      authorize your application to request some of their data.
> 5. If the user approves, then Google gives your application a
>      short-lived access token.
> 6. Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to
>      the request. If Google determines that your request and the token
>      are valid, it returns the requested data.

For additional reference, you can follow this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676817/keep-receiving-login-required-error-when-trying-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem integrating with JavaScript  using googleapis due to version issues not supported greater than 25.0.0.1 but when I was passing credential like this it resolved my problem

```
function uploadFile(tmp_path,_folderID,file_name,contentType,cb){

  var  __fileData = fs.createReadStream(tmp_path);
   var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
            var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
                    client_id,
                    secretKey,
                    redirect_url
                    );
            // Retrieve tokens via token exchange explained above or set them:
            oauth2Client.credentials = {
                access_token: body.access_token,
                refresh_token: refreshToken
            };
            var drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: oauth2Client});
            drive.files.create({
                resource: {
                    name: file_name,
                    parents: _folderID,
                    mimeType: contentType
                },
                media: {
                    mimeType: contentType,
                    body: __fileData
                }
            }, function (err, response) {
               if(err) cb(err,null);
                cb(null,'success');

    })
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, how to get the access_token and refresh token.

Comment: You can check here how to get access token and refresh token  :https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/